# Raise an event from Child View Model

Tags: c#, wpf, delegates

I have a setup as follows.

- ContainerViewModel
- SearchViewModel
- ResultsViewModel

Thats because I wan't to use the SearchView and ResultsView in different parts of my application

My ContainerViewModel has a handle to the other VM's like

```
SearchViewModel searchbViewModel = new SearchbViewModel();
ResultsViewModel resultsViewModel = new ResultsViewModel();
```

Each View Model has their own DataContext

I want to be able to raise an event from the SearchViewModel to the ContainerViewModel to let it know a search has been performed.

This is what I have tried:

ContainerViewModel

```
searchJobViewModel.OnSearchPerformed += SearchJobViewModel_OnSearchPerformed;

public void SearchJobViewModel_OnSearchPerformed()
{

}
```

SearchViewModel

```
public delegate void SearchPerformed();
public SearchPerformed OnSearchPerformed { get; set; }

public void Execute_SearchJobs()
{
  if (OnSearchPerformed != null) 
    OnSearchPerformed();
}
```

When I hit the search button and the Execute_SearchJobs method fires OnSearchPerformed is always null

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does that even compile? I think what you want is an event:

```
public event SearchPerformed OnSearchPerformed;
```

Why your eventhandler is null is probably because the code that added a receiver to the event was not called yet or was called on a different instance of the class. You will need to debug that behaviour or post more code here.

Comment: I think you are right.  The ContainerView XAML has the Search user control in it as in <uc:SearchView..../>.  This fires an instance of the SearchView VM.  Then in the Container VM I am doing SearchViewModel searchViewModel = new SearchViewModel(); which is a different instance. If I remove the creation of this second instance how can I get a handle on the SearchVM from within the ContainerVM?  Keeping in mind I would need to wait until the SearchVM had loaded fully

Comment: Yes - it was on a different instance of the class because I was getting two created.  One from my instance I had created in code and the other because I was attempting to set the DataContext on the UserControl like so 
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <vm:SearchJobViewModel/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>.  I changed to setting my DataContext as part of the usercontrol declaration in the Container Xaml like so <uc:SearchJobView DataContext="{Binding searchbViewModel }"></uc:SearchJobView>.  Thanks for your help